# is this wrong Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i just was reading an article about oojs in MDN  [the article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance),
and it mentioned you should use

```
  Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

I just was wondering if there is a problem if i just use

```
   Teacher.prototype = (Person.prototype);
```

Comment: If you do this, you remove the difference between Teacher and Person, `new Teacher()` now just creates a Person

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Oh yes, the constructor itself could be different

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if you do `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;` then `new Person() instanceof Teacher` is indeed `true` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f25r7vtb/))

Comment: @PatrickRoberts in the linked demo of my comment I did that. Both `new Person() instanceof Teacher` and `new Teacher() instanceof Person` return `true` in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @t.niese my comment applied to classes, not functions: `class Person {}
class Teacher extends Person {}
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
console.log(new Person() instanceof Teacher);` is indeed `false`

Comment: @patrick I have the feeling that the prototype of a class is readonly ...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok yes that's true, but in that case neither `Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)` nor `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype` would have an effect. So then both would be identical with respect to the outcome.

Comment: @JonasWilms fair point. I guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you intend to make any changes to Teacher's prototype?

If yes, then option 2 doesn't work. Any changes you make will affect both of your classes.

If no, then why are you making Teacher in the first place? It will be identical to Person, except for its constructor function.